# jpa entitygraph What is the difference if I use addSubgraph instead of addAttributeNodes?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, fetch, entitygraph

Halo

the two codes below generate the same query.
there doesn't seem to be any difference between the addSubgraph and addAttributeNodes methods...
so why do there exist two methods?

```
        EntityGraph entityGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Academy.class);
        entityGraph.addAttributeNodes("students");
        List<Academy> list = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Academy a")
                .setHint("jakarta.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph)
                                .getResultList();
```

and

```
        EntityGraph entityGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Academy.class);
        entityGraph.addSubgraph("students");
        List<Academy> list = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Academy a")
                .setHint("jakarta.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph)
                                .getResultList();
```

Comment: the second one allows you to define nested graphs

Comment: a ha!, If don't use an netsted graph, there is no difference between the two above.